# C++/CLI, DllExport and /clr:pure

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli, dllexport

Here is a simple native DLL:

*Native.h*:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_NATIVE_DLL
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLAPI Native
{
    public: void f();
};
```

*Native.cpp*:

```
#include "Native.h"

void Native::f()
{
}
```

Build:

```
cl /DBUILDING_NATIVE_DLL /LD Native.cpp
...
    Creating library Native.lib and object Native.exp
```

Now I'd like to use it from a **C++/CLI** application:

*Managed.cpp*:

```
#include "Native.h"

int main()
{
    Native* native = new Native();
    native->f();
}
```

I can build it in **CLR mode "IJW"**:

```
cl /clr Managed.cpp Native.lib
...

/out:Managed.exe
Managed.obj
Native.lib
```

But not in **CLR mode "pure"**:

```
cl /clr:pure Managed.cpp Native.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 4.00.30319.18047
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Managed.cpp
c:\users\...\Native.h(9) : warning C42
72: 'Native::f' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling c
onvention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native cal
ling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::~Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native ca
lling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native cal
ling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native
 calling convention when importing a function.
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Managed.exe
/clrimagetype:pure
Managed.obj
Native.lib
Managed.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000009) "public: void __clrcall
 Native::f(void)" (?f@Native@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall m
ain(void)" (?main@@$$HYMHXZ)
Managed.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall
Native::f(void)" (?f@Native@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall ma
in(void)" (?main@@$$HYMHXZ)
Managed.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

So what seems to break the build is the lack of the native **calling convention**.

And indeed if I specify it:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_NATIVE_DLL
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLAPI Native
{
    public: void __thiscall f();
};
```

it's better:

```
cl /clr:pure Managed.cpp
Native.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 4.00.30319.18047
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Managed.cpp
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native cal
ling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::~Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native ca
lling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::Native' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native cal
ling convention when importing a function.
c:\users\...\Native.h(10) : warning C4
272: 'Native::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native
 calling convention when importing a function.
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Managed.exe
/clrimagetype:pure
Managed.obj
Native.lib
```

But still warnings on generated members.

So here are the questions:

- is it possible to specify the calling convention for a whole class, from which generated members will inherit?
- if the header file does not specify the calling convention and if it can't be modified how to build in **CLR mode "pure"**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try bracketing the `#include` of the native header file with

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "Native.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

Obviously a `/clr:pure` compilation unit cannot have unmanaged *definitions* of functions, but these are only declarations of imports -- it should work.

Overall, however, exporting entire classes is not recommended.  It is much safer to export factory functions and use those for class construction, then return a pointer to an interface (base class with pure virtual members) and use that for member access.  This is what COM does, and the technique is extremely compatible across language and compiler versions.

Comment: Thanks Ben, good try, but the **#pragmas** don't change anything. Good point for the factories, I like the COM approach too, though I don't necessarily use it.